# Using Ekiga from a hotel

Tags: linux, voip

Since Skype crashes whenever someone signs in, signs out, or sends a chat message, it has become unusable and I need to change.  [A post at AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41970/what-floss-skype-alternatives-are-available) lists Ekiga as an alternative.  When I try to use it, I get:

> Ekiga did not manage to configure your network settings automatically. You can still use it, but you need to configure your network settings manually.
>
> Ekiga did not manage to configure your network settings automatically. You can still use it, but you need to configure your network settings manually.
>
> Please see http://wiki.ekiga.org/index.php/Enable_port_forwarding_manually for instructions

However, I'm at a hotel and unable to configure my router.  Can I still use Ekiga?

Answer (score 0):

Unless your router has ports blocked, Ekiga (sip client) should work fine. Are you trying to use it with a SIP account? Ekiga account? Ekiga call out account? or h.323 account? i use Ekiga daily as a sip client and have never had to do any router setup for it to work. (sip uses port 5060 usually) You could try another sip client like Sfl-phone or Linphone.